# How to use spotify SDK via CDN in vue3?

Tags: sdk, vuejs3, spotify, cdn

I'm facing an issue while implementing the Spotify Web Playback SDK as described in their tutorial [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/tutorials/getting-started). The tutorial instructs me to include the following script tag **`<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>`** in my **`index.html`**. However, when I follow these instructions, I encounter the following error in the console:

```
spotify-player.js:18 Uncaught AnthemError: onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady is not defined
    at new t (spotify-player.js:18:9580)
    at a (spotify-player.js:18:10186)
```

[image]

My question is, how do I properly implement a CDN in a Vue 3 project, not just for Spotify but for any future use?

I suspect I should make some changes in my **`main.js`**, but I'm not entirely sure what those changes should be.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

const app = createApp(App)

const pinia = createPinia()

app.use(pinia);

app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out how to deal with it. All you have to do is implement the following code in the component where you want to use CDN:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js'; // or any other cdn
script.async = true;

document.body.appendChild(script);
```